# Output of op-amp circuit with capacitor in feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier

hello i want to solve this question.

i think this is op-amp based integrator circuit.

i followed this tutorial

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_6.html

applied ac gain formula

gain = (1+R2/R1)*(1/(1+j2*pi*R2*C2)

my expected answer should be 1Vrms. but using this equation i am not getting it. can anyone tell me what is my mistake??

[image]

Comment: The easy way is to assume C is almost a short circuit as Zc is 4 orders of magnitude lower than 40k.  Then what is the non-inverting gain?  1+Zf/10k  for Zf=Zc//Rf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another way to look at this is to picture the Bode plot of this circuit, then see where the input frequency fits.

Find the rolloff frequency of the capacitor and the feedback resistor.  What will be the gain at DC?  What will be the gain at "high" frequencies?  At roughly what frequency is the boundary between "low" and "high"?  Where is your frequency of interest with respect to that.  If it's really high, really low, or near the transition?  Based on that, you should be able to come up with a simple estimate of the output voltage just from inpsection.

Answer (score 0):

You have your brackets in the wrong place, should be

gain = 1 + ((R2/R1) * (1/(1+j2*pi*R2*C2))

This formula still misses the frequency - add it before use!

Actually, should probably be the following:

gain = 1 + ((R2/R1) * (1/(1+ j*F*2*pi*R2*C2)) where F = frequency.

Comment: Too brain dead to check the frequency math today ---->

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is totally wrong. It even has no frequency. It resembles a little the right formula. Probably you have copied it inaccurately.

Hopefully you have noticed that the easy form of the gain formula (=no squareroots) has j. It's the complex imaginary unit, the square root of minus one. The formula with j is the complex transfer function for phasor calculus. It holds both the gain and the phase shift in one complex number.